# How can I explain a number of operations formally?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop

Given the following code:

```
Function Fun(int n) {
    int j, k, t=1;
    for (j=0; j<=4*n^2; j+=4) {
        for (k=j; k<=4*sqrt(n); k+=4) {
            t+=8;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to count how many times the command `t+=8;` is executed.

I found, by trying several values for `n`, that it is executed:

[image]

times. But, how can I explain it formally?

Comment: What do you mean by "explain"?

Comment: I found that the command is executed this number of times, using examples.How can justify that it is executed this number of times, without the use of examples?

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
for (j=0; j<=4*n^2; j+=4){
    for (k=j; k<=4*sqrt(n); k+=4){
        t+=8;
    }
}
```

is enough to answer your question.

Notice that it is similar to:

```
for (j=0; j<=n^2; j++){
    for (k=4*j; k<=4*sqrt(n); k+=4){
        t+=8;
    }
}
```

which is similar to:

```
for (j=0; j<=n^2; j++){
    for (k=j; k<=sqrt(n); k++){
        t+=8;
    }
}
```

1) The first `for` shows how many times the second one is executed

2) The  second `for` shows how many times `t+=8;` is executed

Let's explain both parts of **your formula**:

- The second part is related to your second `for`:
  k takes `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)) - j + 1` values for step `j` ( when `j=0` => `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)) + 1` values )
- The first part is related to your first `for`. But **why** do you have `sqrt(n)` instead of `n^2` ? Here is the tricky part. If you analyse when the second loop has effect you'll see that any `j` that is bigger than `sqrt(n)` is useless ( the second "for content" is not executed because the upper limit for `k` is `sqrt(n)` ). This is why in the formula you have `sqrt(n)`.

That happened because your code is in fact similar to:

```
for (j=0; j<=sqrt(n); j++){
    for (k=j; k<=sqrt(n); k++){
        t+=8;
    }
}
```